# confirmation box before closing page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to have a confirmation box before closing the page and not on every page load or navigating away but the confirmation box will just appear when the user closes the window?

Comment: You can't really differentiate. All you have is an `onbeforeunload` event and you cannot know what caused it. You can use some special code with all your links and forms (set a flag that can be read by `beforeunload` event handler), but the back button will still trigger the confirmation box.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { return showPopup(); };
```

but not all browsers support that, and your showPopup function should be standard confirmation window(like alert)

Comment: oh i get it.. but it displays the alert box every time i reload the page or i navigate it away. the thing is i want the confirmation box to display when i close the browser window..